# SQL insert has no results

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

Insert into query from vb program adds no record in access database.

```
database connection class-->
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Data
    Shared dbconnection As OleDbConnection
    Shared dbcommand As OleDbCommand
    Shared dbadapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Shared connectionString As String =     "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Chakana saving and credit\Chakana saving and credit\Chakana.mdb"
Shared dbtable As DataTable
Public Shared Function loadData(query As String, Optional ReturnValue As Boolean = False)
    dbconnection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    dbadapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
    dbtable = New DataTable()
    dbcommand = New OleDbCommand(query)
    dbcommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
    dbadapter.SelectCommand = dbcommand
    dbadapter.SelectCommand.Connection = dbconnection
    dbconnection.Open()
    'MsgBox("query lexecute")
    If ReturnValue = True Then
        dbadapter.Fill(dbtable)
        Return dbtable
    Else
         Return 0
    End If


End Function
```

End Class

function call passing parameter query

```
 query = "INSERT INTO CustomerInfo (ClientId,FirstName) VALUES ('23','abce')"
    Data.loadData(query)
```

other call to function passing a SELECT query works fine but when i try insert query and afterwards open the database from access it has no results

Comment: You are not executing the query passed

Comment: then why is Select query (from other forms) executing correctly when calling this very same function?

    query = "SELECT Password, AccountType FROM Cooperative                  WHERE UserName=" + "'" + Username + "'"
        tdata = Data.loadData(query, True)

Comment: You set your update query into the select command.

Comment: An INSERT query is executed by an ExecuteNonQuery call from a DbCommand. Moreover your _If ReturnValue = True Then_ will not allow to reach the Fill method (also if it is totally wrong calling Fill to Execute an Insert). Your LoadData class cannot do it all, writing a block of code that could handle all the possible variations of a database task is an effort doomed from the start. If you really want to go along this way then use an ORM (Entity Framework, Dapper, name_your_favorite_here)

Comment: I have a working example which shows not only the insert but returning the new primary key https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-new-records-into-53ce3eb1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out 
[OleDbTransaction.Commit Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DbDataAdapter.Update Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab5x5cd(v=vs.110).aspx) which show how to open and commit a transaction within a connection.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing your `DataAdapter` to fill `DataTable` (because returnValue is set to false by default) plus you don't neither need to define returnValue nor `DataAdapter` for just filling a table. I recommend to change your function to something like this:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Data

    Shared connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Chakana saving and credit\Chakana saving and credit\Chakana.mdb"

    Public Shared Function loadData(query As String) As DataTable
        Dim dbtable As New DataTable
        Dim dbcommand As New OleDbCommand(query)
        dbcommand.Connection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        dbcommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
        dbcommand.Connection.Open()
        dbtable.Load(dbcommand.ExecuteReader())
        dbcommand.Connection.Close()
        Return dbtable
    End Function

End Class
```